# React Native scan printers when connected to wifi network and get ip address of the printer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

Hi i'm looking to scan printer devices which are connected to my network in React Native (Android & iOS) and get the selected printer ip address. upto now what i tried is:

[1. https://github.com/leesiongchan/react-native-esc-pos](https://github.com/leesiongchan/react-native-esc-pos) -- Gives me device mac_address

[2. https://github.com/bencomtech/react-native-pos-printer](https://github.com/bencomtech/react-native-pos-printer) -- it gives me Device's id

but i need ip address, is there any modules to detect these type of scenario's for both cross-platforms.
can anyone suggest me to achieve this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you won't be able to find a RN library doing this specific task. You would have to write native implementation and package it as a RN module.

Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan

iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1942/_index.html