# Print a receipt using react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I build a restaurant app using React JS and I want to print a receipt when the order got accepted. The restaurant has a wifi printer and I have no idea how should I connect a printer with that website.

Comment: No need to connect your printer to your website, you just connect the printer with your machine, your OS and browser will do the rest. if you need an example post your sample component code I will update the print option in that

Comment: @sojin. My component is all single-page app. Can you just give me a simple coding example? I will very thank full for that and I want a direct print  like it should not ask for any printer to choose from

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print check this package, this one have the examples of both class and functional components or you can use the simple window.print() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I know we can do this.

1. Windows.print() - When added this native trigger, it'll open the regular print dialog box. Which in further you can select you printer and one can take print out.
2. ReactToPrint - [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) - This library also help you to achieve the same results but in abstracted manner and some over-the-top modifications.

Though, if you're wondering that wherever an order is placed but print should be printed then this might not help but I strongly believe that this will help you figure out something.

Some other useful resources:

1. [React Native scan printers when connected to wifi network and get ip address of the printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294141/react-native-scan-printers-when-connected-to-wifi-network-and-get-ip-address-of)